# vue router - where to store route names?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I'm building a fairly large app using Vue and I have a lot of routes, names and logic behind them. I found a great question/answer [about Vue Router here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020026/what-is-the-best-vue-router-practice-for-very-large-webapplications) and it gave me a lot of ideas, but I wasn't able to find an answer for myself. If I missed something, please feel free to point me in the right direction.

Here are my issues:

1. Renaming hell: whenever I change a name of the route I have to go and find all the `self.$router.replace({ name: 'OldRouteName' })` and change them. Maybe it doesn't sound like a big deal, but it is, especially in a big project
2. Global guard hell: in a way it is related to the #1 where I'm relying on the text literals to analyze `from` and `to` and call my `next({ name: 'RouteName', replace: true })`

There are a few other minor things on the list, but those two are big for me. 
My thought was to create a global object and store route names there something like `Vue.prototype.$myRoutes = {Index:'Index', Home: 'Home'}` etc, but for some reason it doesn't feel right. I hope there is something better out there

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just like you can store [Vuex mutation types in constants](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#using-constants-for-mutation-types), so too can you store route names.

For example

```js
// router/route-names.js
export const INDEX = "Index"
export const HOME = "Home"
```

Now wherever you need them, you just import from this file

```js
import { INDEX, HOME } from '@/router/route-names'
```

Making changes means only editing one file.

---

For point #2, you can store extra data in each [route's `meta` property](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html). For example

```js
{
  name: ROUTE_A,
  path: '/route/a',
  meta: {
    nextRoute: { name: ROUTE_B, replace: true }
  }
}
```

Then you can use

```js
next(from.meta.nextRoute)
```